# Definition of an ellipse in a picture opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I don’t understand how to define an ellipse in an image. Here is my code on opencv c++.But he draws ellipses on all contours, even those that don’t look like ellipses at all.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include<string>
#include <windows.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
   int main()
{
    int low_H = 0, low_S =77, low_V = 80;
    int high_H =208, high_S =255, high_V = 255;
    Mat src,gray;
    src = imread("C:\\Roads\\pits\\27.jpg");
    if (src.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    resize(src,src,Size(800,600));
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cvtColor(src, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(gray, gray, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    inRange(gray, Scalar(low_H, low_S, low_V), Scalar(high_H, high_S, high_V), gray);
    findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
    namedWindow("Gray", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Gray", gray);
    Moments moment1,moment2; int x1,x2, y1,y2;
    for (auto i : contours) {
         moment1 = moments(i, 1); 
         x1 = int(moment1.m10 / moment1.m00);
         y1 = int(moment1.m01 / moment1.m00);
         RotatedRect temp = minAreaRect(Mat(i));
        if (i.size() > 40) {
          ellipse(src, temp, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
       }
    }
    namedWindow("Ready", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Ready", src);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

I need to find out a method by which it can be determined whether the contour is an ellipse. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfiRj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaHbG.png)

Comment: Don't tag C++ question with the C tag; you will get downvoted horribly for doing so.

Comment: If i understand well, the goal is to determine if a given vector of points corresponds to an ellipse. The simplest characterisation of an ellipse I know is CM = R1 u cos(theta) + R2 v sin(theta), where C is the center, M a point of the ellipse, R1 and R2 the rays, u and v the normalised orthogonal vectors (axis). You should try to determine these parameters from the vector and then measure the reliability (distance between calculated ellipse and vector) of this estimation. If the distance is high, it is not an ellipse

Comment: Sorry, but  is theta the angle between the rays R1 and R2?

Comment: No theta is the angle of M with respect to first axis u. Don't forget @name when you adress a message to someone